# como puedo arreglar este error de git bash?

Tags: git, windows, bash

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé que hacer para arreglar este error,

```
Error: Could not fork child process: Resource temporarily unavailable (-1)
DLL rebasing may be required; see 'rebaseall / rebase --help.
```

por favor si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería eternamente

Comment: https://github.com/mintty/wsltty/issues/6

Answer (score 0):

hola encontré esta solución en https://github.com/mintty/wsltty/issues/6 amime soluciono el problema.

Here is the fix.
1 Go to you Windows Defender Security Center settings
2 Click on App & Browser Control
3 At the bottom click on the "Exploit Protection Settings" link
4 Go to "Program Settings" and click on the "Add program to customize" -> "Choose exact file path"
5 Navigate to "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe" and add it
6 Override and turn off the following:
Mandatory ASLR
Randomize memory allocations (Bottom-up ASLR)
7 Click "Apply" and now everything should work fine.

Comment: No olvides que estás en [es.so]. La respuesta debe estar en español. Además, lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.